# BroadcastReceiver android - Sometimes it continues after closing the app, sometimes not

Tags: java, android

I have a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// show will check date and return 0 or 1.

        if(show == 1) {

            //notify
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            showNotification(context, "title", "description", intent2);

        }

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentn = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentn, 0);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

// set next alarm, I also have this in my MainActivity to run it first time every 15 min (900 sec):

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) {
            alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000*900), pendingIntent);
        }
        else{
            alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000*900), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

In manifest I have this:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The problem is sometimes it plays, sometimes not. Sometimes when I close the app it continue to play, sometimes not. Any ideas why?
I'm testing in android 8.

Comment: hi. Have you tested on Android 5?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "close the app"? And, what device(s) are you testing on?

Comment: @JavadDehban only on kitkat it was ok.

Comment: @CommonsWare When user in android multitask closes it: pressing X or swipe it to the right. I tested in kitkat api 19 (works ok), and in emulator api 27 (android 8). On android 8 app doesn't show notifications after I close it (sometimes it shows if I put small value in eg: 1000*60 but 1000*900 never shows).

Comment: probably, you need to write code to ignore battery optimization as described here : https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

With that, you are saying that the *sender* of the broadcast has to hold this permission, and that is incorrect.

Your app needs a `<uses-permission>` element for `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, though.